# Как заменить символы в столбце?

Tags: sql-server

Подскажите пожалуйста, как заменить с 1 по 4 символы в столбце типа varchar?

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE t
   SET
       FIELD_NAME = REPLACE(FIELD_NAME,SUBSTRING(FIELD_NAME,1,4),'new_string')
FROM TABLE_NAME t
```